# Visual C++ and the .NET Framework?

Tags: c++, .net, visual-studio

When writing programs using Visual C++ compiler, is the code true C++ or some wacky .NET knock off of C++? Like how VB.NET is different from standard Visual Basic. I'd like to begin GUI development in C++, and I already know VB.NET, so the Visual C++ IDE would be easy and comfortable for me to use. I just don't want to have to learn a .NET knock off of true C++.

Comment: VC++ supports both standards-compliant C++ AND the wacky .NET knock-offs.

Comment: @CoryNelson Well, I wouldn't necessarily say *standards-compliant*.

Comment: What would you recommend as an alternative? I've heard Gtk and Qt are good, but I have no experience with them

Comment: For native win32 gui apps, you can of course use the C api directly, or the MFC (i don't recommend if your wanting to stay pure native as it incorporates some aspects of .NET winforms) , or my personal favorite ATL + WTL. The latter is pure native and will have the windows look and feel. Gtk and QT do make libs for windows, QT being the, IMHO better of the two, however without a little bit of intricate knowledge of the api the gui's these two frameworks leave a lot lacking.

Comment: I've decided to use Visual C++, thanks for clearing things up

Comment: @johnathon Concur with WTL. it produces incredibly efficient native winapi code, which, of course, explains the move by MS to drop it. They're so managed-code-centric it is laughable at this point. I really do like WTL, especially if you're familiar with the Win32 api to begin with.

Comment: @WhozCraig Agreed, just wish that it did cover more of the aspects of the operating system than just the windowing aspect, however it does that quite well, and as such i cant complain about it. QT being a complete framework has very nice classes for dealing with things that in native code is usually left up to the use of COM for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being a Windows developer, sooner or later you will have to deal with .NET in some form. This is unavoidable. Don't be too much afraid.

On your question. C++ in VisualStudio is real C++ that is implemented according to the standard. To use it you do not need to know anything about .NET. You still need to learn Win32 that has nothing to do with .NET. Win32 is directly accessible from C++.

There is a thing called C++/CLI. It allows using .NET classes, idioms, etc. It is a stand alone thing. You can use it if you want, if not it will not bother you.

Comment: You know, I think I'll use Visual C++ and see how it goes. Thanks for the help

Comment: That's not true. Plenty of Windows programmers never deal with .NET. There's no reason to push someone there.

Comment: I am not pushing anybody anywhere. Where have you taken this? Note that `later` may happen in a decade.

Comment: What might happen in a decade is irrelevant. There is no reason to simply assume that .NET is necessary.

Comment: Once again, I am not saying it is necessary. I am not a .NET fan. I am saying that it is used. This means that a chance that somebody will be in a situation that requires some piece of .net dev (ex: create a power shell extension) is relatively high.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler has settings for both options- an interoperation language known as C++/CLI, and real C++, which is just as much C++ as any other implementation you might wish to find, and has absolutely nothing whatsoever to do with .NET, ever, although the IDE still contains various shortcuts/syntax highlighting/etc for the C++/CLI mode. Don't let them confuse you.